# Can a hash index become inconsistent for "no reason"?

Tags: postgresql, index

Of course, when i say no reason i mean "apparently" no reason because nothing happened on the server *(forced shutdowns, data corruption, deadlocks, etc...)*.

I ask this because, there was an application which executed a simple select on PostgreSQL:

```
select * from product where barcode = '9990000088355'
```

Which returned nothing, but there was a record in the table with `barcode = 9990000088355`. There was an index specific for this field, and after reindexing it, the problem was solved and the query fetched the record.

So, is there a reason for this issue to happen, and can i do something to prevent this or at least see if there is a problem with other indices of another tables?

Comment: Which minor version of PostgreSQL?  Do you have replication?

Comment: 9.3, no replication

Comment: If that happens, it's a bug. Even if it's after a crash or forced shutdown or deadlock, it's a bug. What is the **exact** version you are running? `SELECT version()` please. Also, please show the output of the query `SHOW fsync;`. Have you *ever* had `fsync` or `full_page_writes` set to `off`?

Comment: Also, is there any chance you took a copy of the database directory before you `reindex`ed? If so, it might be useful to have the damaged index and the corresponding table.

Comment: The version is `PostgreSQL 9.3.9, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit`. Both `fsync` and `full_page_writes` were always on. Actually, before doing the reindex i really did a pg_dump to get the database to my computer, and didn't test the select query to see if it returned the values... maybe pg_dump fixed the index?

Comment: Is the barcode field alphanumeric? You may need to do a btrim() on it to make sure that there aren't any hidden spaces. If you do this enough, it would make sense to create a function index on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FINALLY, after so much time i found the cause of this problem. I actually saw the machine where postgres was running suffering a hard reset, after that, the  exact error happened.
Turns out the index i was using was a HASH index instead of the default B-Tree.
So, looking up on postgres documentation, the first thing i saw was a giant yellow warning explicitly stating about it's unsafety when a crash occurs.
Taken from the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/indexes-types.html):

> **Caution**
>   Hash index operations are not presently WAL-logged, so hash indexes might need to be rebuilt with REINDEX after a database crash if there were unwritten changes. Also, changes to hash indexes are not replicated over streaming or file-based replication after the initial base backup, so they give wrong answers to queries that subsequently use them. For these reasons, hash index use is presently discouraged.

What i did was simply drop the hash index and create a new one with B-tree algorithm. So far it seems to be the working solution.

Comment: good on you for posting a good question, and coming back over a year later with a good answer.

Comment: necromancy at its finest!